# Unable to execute scala code on Azure DataBricks cluster

Tags: python, scala, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I am trying to setup a Development environment for DataBricks, So my developers can write code using VSCODE IDE(or some other IDE) and execute the code against the DataBricks Cluster.

So I went through the Documentation of [DataBricks Connect](https://datathirst.net/blog/2019/3/7/databricks-connect-finally) and did the setup as suggested in the document.
https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#overview

Post the Setup I am able to execute python code on Azure DataBricks cluster, but not with **Scala code**

[image]

While Running the setup I found that it is saying **Skipping scala command test on windows**, I am not sure whether I am missing some configuration here.

Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: @emzero, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58941808/how-to-properly-access-dbutils-in-scala-when-using-databricks-connect

Comment: HI All, Did anyone came across the same issue??

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error but just a statement that says `databricks-connect test` is skipping testing scala code on windows you can still execute code from local machine on cluster using databricks-connect, you need to add the jars from `databricks-connect get-jar-dir` directory to your project structure in IDE as described in this documentation steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect#intellij-scala-or-java

Also note that when using azure databricks you enter a generic Databricks Host along with your workspace id(org-id) when you execute `databricks-connect configure`

eg- `https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net/o=?xxxx` instead of `https://adb-xxxx.yz.azuredatabricks.net`