# How to use dbutils in a SparkListener on Databricks

Tags: azure, scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

Using [Azure Databricks Runtime 9.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/9.1), I want to start a [SparkListener](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/SparkListener.html) and access [dbutils features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils) inside of the SparkListener.

This listener should log some information on the start of the Spark application. It should list out the file system (as a simple example) using `dbutils.fs.ls`.

The question [How to properly access dbutils in Scala when using Databricks Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58941808/how-to-properly-access-dbutils-in-scala-when-using-databricks-connect) is super close to what I'm looking to do but they are focused on dbconnect whereas **I want dbutils on a SparkListener**. It does point to the [dbutils api library on MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils#--databricks-utilities-api-library) page where it seems to indicate that I need only specify the correct target and version of the [dbutils-api package](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/dbutils-api).

In the sample listener below...

- If I do not include the `import com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder.dbutils` the jar fails to compile since I reference `dbutils` in the `onApplicationStart` method.
- When I do include the import, it successfully compiles.

  - However, it fails to initialize the SparkListener.
  - I receive a NullPointerException after it tries to execute the `dbutils.fs.ls` command.

Any thoughts and/or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

### Sample Listener Using dbutils on Application Start

```scala
package my.custom.listener

import java.util.logging.Logger
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.{SparkListener, SparkListenerApplicationStart}
import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}

// Crucial Import
import com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder.dbutils

class LibraryListener extends SparkListener {
  private var isDatabricks = false
  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[LibraryListener])

 override def onApplicationStart(applicationStart: SparkListenerApplicationStart): Unit = {
    log.info("HELLO WORLD!")
    log.info(s"App Name ${applicationStart.appName}")
    log.info(s"User  ${applicationStart.sparkUser}")

    isDatabricks = !(sys.env.get("DATABRICKS_RUNTIME_VERSION").isEmpty)

    if (isDatabricks){
      log.info("WE ARE USING DATABRICKS!")
      // Dummy example of using dbutils
      log.info(dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/"))
    }
  }
}
```

### Error Message From Spark Listener Initialization

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception when registering SparkListener
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.setupAndStartListenerBus(SparkContext.scala:2829)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:701)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DatabricksILoop$.$anonfun$initializeSharedDriverContext$1(DatabricksILoop.scala:347)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ClassLoaders$.withContextClassLoader(ClassLoaders.scala:29)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DatabricksILoop$.initializeSharedDriverContext(DatabricksILoop.scala:347)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DatabricksILoop$.getOrCreateSharedDriverContext(DatabricksILoop.scala:277)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverCorral.driverContext(DriverCorral.scala:229)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverCorral.<init>(DriverCorral.scala:102)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverDaemon.<init>(DriverDaemon.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverDaemon$.create(DriverDaemon.scala:287)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverDaemon$.wrappedMain(DriverDaemon.scala:362)
    at com.databricks.DatabricksMain.$anonfun$main$1(DatabricksMain.scala:117)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.DatabricksMain.$anonfun$withStartupProfilingData$1(DatabricksMain.scala:425)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$1(UsageLogging.scala:395)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.executeThunkAndCaptureResultTags$1(UsageLogging.scala:484)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperationWithResultTags$4(UsageLogging.scala:504)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:266)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:261)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:258)
    at com.databricks.DatabricksMain.withAttributionContext(DatabricksMain.scala:85)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:305)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:297)
    at com.databricks.DatabricksMain.withAttributionTags(DatabricksMain.scala:85)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(UsageLogging.scala:479)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags$(UsageLogging.scala:404)
    at com.databricks.DatabricksMain.recordOperationWithResultTags(DatabricksMain.scala:85)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:395)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:367)
    at com.databricks.DatabricksMain.recordOperation(DatabricksMain.scala:85)
    at com.databricks.DatabricksMain.withStartupProfilingData(DatabricksMain.scala:425)
    at com.databricks.DatabricksMain.main(DatabricksMain.scala:116)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverDaemon.main(DriverDaemon.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder$$anon$1.invoke(DBUtilsHolder.scala:17)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.fs(Unknown Source)
    at my.custom.listener.LibraryListener.<init>(LibraryListener.scala:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$loadExtensions$1(Utils.scala:3077)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.loadExtensions(Utils.scala:3066)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$setupAndStartListenerBus$1(SparkContext.scala:2810)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$setupAndStartListenerBus$1$adapted(SparkContext.scala:2809)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.setupAndStartListenerBus(SparkContext.scala:2809)
    ... 33 more
```

### build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'scala'
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use Scala 2.13 in our library project
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.15'

    // Crucial Implementation
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/dbutils-api
    implementation group: 'com.databricks', name: 'dbutils-api_2.12', version: '0.0.5'

    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.32'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.12', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.12', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:3.2.9'
    testImplementation 'org.scalatestplus:junit-4-13_2.12:3.2.2.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.32'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.2.0'
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
}
```

Thank you for any insights!

Comment: Hi, have you tried checking this? https://github.com/mspnp/spark-monitoring

Comment: @dadadima - Thank you for commenting! Unfortunately, the spark-monitoring listener does not use dbutils. It is a great example of a well written spark listener but doesn't have a good example to learn how dbutils can be accessed in the listener.

Comment: Specifically - what functionality of dbutils do you need? dbutils may need fully initialized SparkSession to work, and `ApplicationStart` could be too early.

Comment: Thanks for replying @AlexOtt !  I need dbutils.fs.mounts() so perhaps I just need to try somewhere else like on JobEnd! I will give that a shot!